# Deactivate earlier app bundles in Google Play Console when update

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to upgrade the app already publish via Google Play console. Because the earlier version of app has some permission violation, I want to release a new version to replace it. But there is no way to choose which version of app bundle to be deactivated.

In the screenshot below, the newest version to be published is 127, the 2nd latest version is 123, but the one on the production track is 114 for example.

Is there a way to choose version 114 in the deactivated app bundles?

I tried to move version 123 into the "retained app bundles", but the earlier version of the bundle still can not be chosen to be added to "[Deactivated app bundles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUwQb.png)"

This is [the list of app bundles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31XvN.png) I have.

Comment: You mentioned a screenshot but nothing is attached.

Comment: sorry, I forget to add the screen, just updated with images.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a policy violation, developer will have to use "Full rollout" instead of "staged rollout". That is why I can not publish the app, after I change it to 100% rollout, problem solved.